# Powershell email sending with an error

Tags: powershell, email

I am trying to send an email with the PowerShell function *Send-MailMessage*, and I am in front of various issues that are quite strange :

- First of all, the *-To* parameter is not proposed when I write this function in the PowerShell ISE. And if I try to add it anyway, if have the following error 
  `Send-MailMessage : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'True'.`
- So to bypass this problem, I found that I could send an email to someone using the *-Cc* parameter. So my call to *Send-MailMessage* looks like the following

`Send-MailMessage -Body $body -BodyAsHtml $true -From "senderadress@safrangroup.com" -Cc $recipient -Priority High - Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) -SmtpServer "my.smtp.server" -Subject ("My subject") -Attachments "RESSOURCES/logo.png"`

The problem is that when this line is executing, it's raising an error :

`Send-MailMessage : The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.`

But the most strange here is that the mail has been send to the personn specified in *-Cc*... I don't understand why I can't add this *-To* argument, and most of all why it is sending the message even if there is an error...

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the full value of `$recipient`?

Comment: I can't publish the real value, but it's exactly like "name.subname@group.com"

Comment: Not sure if it's the only problem, but `-BodyAsHtml $true` is (afaik) wrong, it should either be only `-BodyAsHtml` or `-BodyAsHtml:$true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the syntax

`Get-Command Send-MailMessage -Syntax`

the parameter `[-BodyAsHtml]` is you add is type of switch and not expecting `$true` value. You can specify `-BodyAsHtml:$true`

`Send-MailMessage [-To] <string[]> [-Subject] <string> [[-Body] <string>] [[-SmtpServer] <string>] -From <string> [-Attachments <string[]>] [-Bcc <string[]>] [-BodyAsHtml] [-Encoding <Encoding>] [-Cc <string[]>] [-DeliveryNotificationOption <DeliveryNotificationOptions>] [-Priority <MailPriority>] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-UseSsl] [-Port <int>] [<CommonParameters>]`

Comment: Thanks, that was perfectly what I did wrong. I'll be more carefull with the syntax now. Thanks a lot !